# How can I access "each estimater " in scikit-learn pipelines?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

How can I access `"Log"` in pipelines?

```py
pipelines = {
    "Log": Pipeline(
        [("scl", StandardScaler()), ("est", LogisticRegression(random_state=1))]
    ),
    "Rf": Pipeline([("est", RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1))]),
    "Rf_Pipeline": Pipeline(
        [
            ("scl", StandardScaler()),
            ("reduct", PCA(n_components=10, random_state=1)),
            ("est", RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)),
        ]
    ),
}


Pipelines.item(Log)
```

Currently I get:

```
NameError: name 'Log' is not defined
```

Comment: Getting an item from a dictionary, you can use `pipelines["Log"]` or `pipelines.get("Log")`.

Comment: Your pipeline is named `pipelines`, not `Pipelines` with a capital initial L (typo).

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline objects can be viewed as dictionaries. In your case, you have stored multiple pipelines into a dictionary. To access the different keys (pipelines) you can simply use `dict['key']` or `dict.get['key']`.

1. For the first level (sub pipelines), simply use `dict['key']`
2. For the second level, (steps inside sub pipelines), again, you can fetch the `dict` with steps using `named_steps` and then refer to each step the same way.

Here is a the code -

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

pipelines = {
    "Log": Pipeline(
        [("scl", StandardScaler()), ("est", LogisticRegression(random_state=1))]
    ),
    "Rf": Pipeline([("est", RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1))]),
    "Rf_Pipeline": Pipeline(
        [
            ("scl", StandardScaler()),
            ("reduct", PCA(n_components=10, random_state=1)),
            ("est", RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)),
        ]
    ),
}

first_subpipeline = pipelines['Log']
second_step_first_subpipeline =  pipelines['Log'].named_steps['est']

print(first_subpipeline)
print(second_step_first_subpipeline)
```

```
Pipeline(steps=[('scl', StandardScaler()),
                ('est', LogisticRegression(random_state=1))])

LogisticRegression(random_state=1)
```

Comment: I tried this code and everything is clear now. Thank you so much!!