# Pipelines→GridSearchCV(estimator = pipelines['key'] ..doen`t work. Why?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

Sorry I revised. I wanna use "pipepines[Log]".
I understand how to access the pipeline
from this answer.
[How can I access "each estimater " in scikit-learn pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67254356/how-can-i-access-each-estimater-in-scikit-learn-pipelines)

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

pipelines = {
    "Log": Pipeline(
        [("scl", StandardScaler()), ("est", LogisticRegression(random_state=1))]
    ),
    "Rf": Pipeline([("est", RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1))]),
    "Rf_Pipeline": Pipeline(
        [
            ("scl", StandardScaler()),
            ("reduct", PCA(n_components=10, random_state=1)),
            ("est", RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)),
        ]
    ),
}

first_subpipeline = pipelines['Log']
second_step_first_subpipeline =  pipelines['Log'].named_steps['est']

print(first_subpipeline)
print(second_step_first_subpipeline)
```

But it didn`t work in this code somehow.Why?

```
lr_pg={
    'pca__n_components':[11,12],
    'est__C':[0.1, 1.0, 10.0],
}

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipelines['Log'] #here
,
                  param_grid=lr_pg,
                  scoring='f1',
                  cv=2,
                  return_train_score=False)

gs.fit(X,y)
```

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter pca for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('scl', StandardScaler()),
                ('est', LogisticRegression(random_state=1))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Comment: `rf_pipeline` contains a random forest classifier. Random forest classifier doesn't use a parameter `C=`. Your parameter grid for your CV _does_ contain `C`. That's what the error is telling you

Comment: sorry, I revised. I wanted to use pipeline['Log']. But your comment is very helpful. when I want to use rf_pipeline, I will keep it in my mind .

Comment: Again, the new error tells you exactly what the problem is. Your param grid contains `pca` but you only use pca in your `rf_pipeline`, not `Log`/ You need to make sure your parameters match your estimators and transformers for your gridsearch

Comment: Please do not use both inverse quotes *and* indentation for your code snippets (edited).

Comment: Very helpful!! Thank your for your advice. I noticed that and add pca . Then Everything is working now. `Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()),
                          ('pca', PCA(random_state=1)),
                          ('est', LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',
                                                     random_state=1))])`